# passing value with php and input "disabled"

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I just want pass a value with an input in "disabled" but when i tried to echo it just print nothing.

This is my code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
         <label style="color:white;" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Ayudante </label>
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <input type="text" value="<?=$usuario[1]?>"  class="form-control" name="ayudante" placeholder="Nombre del ayudante" disabled="true">
                </div>
    </div>
```

How can I do this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a hidden input to post that value, all browsers treat disabled inputs as read-only.

```
<div class="form-group">
         <label style="color:white;" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Ayudante </label>
                <div class="col-xs-7">
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$usuario[1]?>" name="ayudante" placeholder="Nombre del ayudante" >
<input type="text" value="<?=$usuario[1]?>"  class="form-control" name="ayudante" placeholder="Nombre del ayudante" disabled="true">
                </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**"A** `disabled` **control's value isn't submitted with the form."** ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input))

Use a hidden input for functionality.

```
<input type="text" value="<?=$usuario[1]?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del ayudante" disabled="true"><!--What the user sees-->
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$usuario[1]?>" name="ayudante"><!--What gets submitted-->
```

---

Keep in mind that a user could use JS or developer tools to change the value of the `hidden` input, so always check it server-side.